# Comparação de hashes em PHP

Tags: php, hash

Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma comparação com duas *hashes* de tipos diferentes e descobrir se o conteúdo delas são iguais ou não?

**Por exemplo**: Tenho uma *hash* em SHA512 e outra em MD5 (pode ser qualquer outro tipo de *hash*) que foram criadas a partir do mesmo texto. Usando o PHP gostaria de comparar as duas e descobrir se são iguais ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não da para fazer esse comparação(ou conversão) a partir hash. Os modos para conseguir a correspondência das hash é tendo o texto cifrado e verificando para as duas opções.

Dependendo para o que você quer da para consultar banco de dados de hash quebradas.  Exemplo https://hashkiller.co.uk/